# Drawing the $x$-axis as the line $y=0$ and drawing the $y$-axis as the line $x=0$: convention or rule?

Tags: graphing-functions, convention

Suppose we're given $f(x) = 120 +20 \sin(2\pi x)$. The question is to draw a diagram of this function for $x\in [0,1]$ (give or take). Would you consider the diagram below to be correct? (I.e. with the $x$-axis at $y=120$.)

The question is of course: Is it a convention or a rule that the $x$-axis is the line $y=0$ and that the $y$-axis is the line $x=0$?

[image: The graph of the function where the $x$-axis is drawn as $y=120$.]

(Please imagine that I labled the axes $x$ and $y$.)

---

Personally, I would say that the diagram is fine. There's no ambiguity and no mathematical erros (as far as I can tell).

Comment: No problem with this diagram as long as you label everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is fine !

$x$- axis: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: y=0\}$,

$y$- axis: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x=0\}$.

Comment: Note that in my diagram, $x$-axis: $\big\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : y=120\big\}$. Is this still fine?

Comment: My answer (which I have deleted) was intended to be a comment on this answer: I disagree, and I don't believe it is fine.